# Open source software for medical image processing

Tags: open-source, images, scientific-computing

I am looking for an open source software / application which is used by researchers / doctors / practitioners at hospitals / clinics to visualize patients information in order to diagnose problems. Usually such tools are computationally intensive and they are not serialized.

For example: FreeSurfer is a tool which performs brain imagery analysis. The input to such type of applications are the scanned images of the patients.

Please note - I am not looking for software / application which generates statistics using patients information or maintain records of the patients in hospitals / clinics. Further, the application need not be focused on analysis of brain only.

Answer (score 2):

[ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) is widely used in the medical community, there are a large number of plugins available and it's very easy to write your own plugins to automate complex tasks.